# Basic purchase system in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

In my game exists a opportunity to obtain a COIN, with a certain amount it is possible to release new skins.

Currently the coin score, are being stored correctly.

I have UI canvas where there skins options, I want to know how to do to be purchased these skins if the player has enough coins, or that nothing happens if it does not have enough.

Follow the codes below.

CoinScore

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class BeeCoinScore: MonoBehaviour
{

    public static BeeCoinScore instance;

    public static int coin = 0;  
    public int currentCoin = 0;
    string highScoreKey = "totalCoin";

    Text CoinScore;                      // Reference to the Text component.


    void Awake ()
    {
        // Set up the reference.
        CoinScore = GetComponent <Text> ();

    }
    void Start(){

        //Get the highScore from player prefs if it is there, 0 otherwise.
        coin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(highScoreKey, 0);    
    }
    public void AddBeeCoinScore (int _point) {

        coin += _point;
        GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Bee Coins: " + coin;

    }


    void Update ()
    {
        // Set the displayed text to be the word "Score" followed by the score value.
        CoinScore.text = "Bee Coins: " + coin;
    }


    void OnDisable(){

        //If our scoree is greter than highscore, set new higscore and save.
        if(coin>currentCoin){
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(highScoreKey, coin);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }

}
```

Script to add points to CoinScore

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BeeCoin : MonoBehaviour {

    public int point;
    private float timeVida;
    public float tempoMaximoVida;

    private BeeCoinScore coin;

    AudioSource coinCollectSound;

    void Awake() {


        coin = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("BeeCoin").GetComponent<BeeCoinScore> () as BeeCoinScore;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        coinCollectSound = GameObject.Find("SpawnControllerBeeCoin").GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D colisor)
    {
        if (colisor.gameObject.CompareTag ("Bee")) {


            coinCollectSound.Play ();

            coin.AddBeeCoinScore (point);
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }

        if (colisor.gameObject.tag == "Floor") {
            Destroy (gameObject, 1f);
        }
    }

}
```

My UI canvas SHOP It's pretty basic, it has 4 images related skins, with price: 100, 200, 300 and 400 coins, 4 buttons to buy below each image, and a button to leave.

C# if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure how you wrote a game if you don't know how to create an unlock system. `if(coins >= skinCost) {unlockSkin(); coins -= skinCost; }`

Comment: I try `beeCoin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(highScoreKey, 0);    if (beeCoin >= price) { Debug.Log("Need more coins!");} if (beeCoin >= price) {addSkin();Debug.Log("Skin ADDED"); beeCoins -= price;} `but no sucess...

Comment: you have the same if-statement twice in a row `if (beeCoin >= price)`... the first one should be `if (beeCoin < price)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  solve my problem.

On the "buy" button have attached the script `BuySkin`

And the script  `BeeCoinScore` i added `TakeBeeScore`,
deleted: `if (coin> current Coin) {}`, into the void OnDisable

Now it is working perfectly.

BuySkin Script.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.UI;


    public class BuySkin : MonoBehaviour {

        public int price;

        public void OnClick()
        {
            if (BeeCoinScore.coin >= price) {

                BeeCoinScore.coin -= price;
                Debug.Log ("New skin added");
            }

            if (BeeCoinScore.coin < price) {

                Debug.Log ("Need more coins!");
            }
        }
     }
```

BeeCoinScore script.

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.UI;
   using System.Collections;

     public class BeeCoinScore: MonoBehaviour
      {

       public static BeeCoinScore instance;
       public static int coin = 0;  
       public int currentCoin = 0;
       string totalCoinKey = "totalCoin";

       Text CoinScore; // Reference to the Text component.


       void Awake ()
       {
       // Set up the reference.
       CoinScore = GetComponent <Text> ();

       }
       public void Start(){

       //Get the highScore from player prefs if it is there, 0 otherwise.
       coin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(totalCoinKey, 0);    
       }
       public void AddBeeCoinScore (int _point) {

       coin += _point;
       GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Bee Coins: " + coin;

       }

       public void TakeBeeCoinScore (int _point) {

       coin -= _point;
       GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Bee Coins: " + coin;

       }


       void Update ()
       {
       // Set the displayed text to be the word "Score" followed by the score value.
       CoinScore.text = "Bee Coins: " + coin;
       }


       void OnDisable(){

       PlayerPrefs.SetInt(totalCoinKey, coin);
       PlayerPrefs.Save();

    }
}
```